# Arry to string conversion Magento 2 webapi - with snippet

Tags: magento2, php, array

I have this code in a module to recalculate Magento 2 shipping rate

```
  public function getAddressHash($request)
    {     
    $addressCondition = $this->objectManager->create('Magesales\Shippingrules\Model\Rule\Condition\Address');
        $addressAttributes = $addressCondition->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();
        $hash = '';
        foreach ($addressAttributes as $code => $label) {
            $hash .= $request->getData($code) . $label;
        }
        return md5($hash);
    }
```

But when I go to checkout, it shows no rating, as it has not yet been calculated. When a customer inserts the zipcode, Magento 2 is supposed to return shipping rates value. But at the first attempt I received the notice:

> Notice:  Array to string conversion in
>   `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magesales/Shippingrules/Model/Validator.php`
>   on **line 295**

How can I possibly solve that? It just works on the second attempt.

**File**  - Validator.php

```
<?php
namespace Magesales\Shippingrules\Model;


class Validator extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject

{
    protected $adjustments = array();

protected $objectManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

public function init($request)
{
    $this->setRequest($request);
    return $this;
}

public function applyRulesTo($rates)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $affectedIds = array();

    foreach ($rates as $rate){
        $this->adjustments[$this->getKey($rate)] = array(
            'fee'    => 0,
            'totals' => $this->initTotals(),
            'ids'    => array(),
        );
        $affectedIds[$this->getKey($rate)] = array();
    }

    foreach ($this->getValidRules() as $rule){
        $rule->setFee(0);

        $group = array();
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item){
            if (!($rule->getActions()->validate($item))){
                continue;
            }
            $group[$item->getItemId()] = $item;
        }

        if (!$group){
            continue;
        }

        $subTotals = $this->aggregateTotals($group, $request->getFreeShipping());
        if ($rule->validateTotals($subTotals)){

            $rule->calculateFee($subTotals, $request->getFreeShipping());

            foreach ($rates as $rate){
                $currentIds = array_keys($group);
                $oldIds     = $affectedIds[$this->getKey($rate)];
                if ($rule->match($rate) && !count(array_intersect($currentIds, $oldIds))){

                    $affectedIds[$this->getKey($rate)] = array_merge($currentIds, $oldIds);

                    $a = $this->adjustments[$this->getKey($rate)];
                    $a['fee'] += $rule->getFee();


                    $handling = $rule->getHandling();
                    if (is_numeric($handling)){
                        if($rule->getCalc() == \Magesales\Shippingrules\Model\Rule::CALC_DEDUCT){
                            $a['fee'] -= $rate->getPrice() * $handling /100;
                        } else {
                            $a['fee'] += $rate->getPrice() * $handling /100;
                        }
                    }

                    if ($rule->removeFromRequest()){                            
                        foreach ($subTotals as $k=>$value){
                            if (isset($a['totals'][$k])){
                                $a['totals'][$k] += $value;
                            }
                        }                            
                        $a['ids'] = array_merge($a['ids'], array_keys($group));
                    }

                    if($rule->getRateMax() > 0){
                        $a['fee'] = ($a['fee'] > 0 ? 1: -1) * min(abs($a['fee']),$rule->getRateMax());
                    }

                    if($rule->getRateMin() > 0){
                        if($rule->getCalc() == \Magesales\Shippingrules\Model\Rule::CALC_DEDUCT){                                $a['fee'] = ($a['fee'] <= 0 ? -1: 1) * max(abs($a['fee']),$rule->getRateMin());
                        } else {
                            $a['fee'] = ($a['fee'] >= 0 ? 1: -1) * max(abs($a['fee']),$rule->getRateMin());
                        }
                    }
                    if ($rule->getShipMin() > 0){
                        if ($rate->getCost() + $a['fee'] < $rule->getShipMin()){
                            $a['fee'] = $rule->getShipMin() - $rate->getCost();
                        }
                    }

                    if ($rule->getShipMax() > 0){
                        if ($rate->getCost() + $a['fee'] > $rule->getShipMax()){
                            $a['fee'] = $rule->getShipMax()  - $rate->getCost();
                        }
                    }

                    $this->adjustments[$this->getKey($rate)] = $a;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function needNewRequest($rate)
{
    $k = $this->getKey($rate);
    if (empty($this->adjustments[$k]))
        return false;

    return (count($this->adjustments[$k]['ids']));
}

public function getNewRequest($rate)
{
    $a = $this->adjustments[$this->getKey($rate)];

    $totalsToDeduct = $a['totals'];
    $idsToRemove    = $a['ids'];

    $newRequest = clone $this->getRequest();

    $newItems = array();
    foreach ($newRequest->getAllItems() as $item){
        $id = $item->getItemId();
        if (in_array($id, $idsToRemove)){
            continue;
        }
        $newItems[] = $item;
    }
    $newRequest->setAllItems($newItems);

    $newRequest->setPackageValue($newRequest->getPackageValue() - $totalsToDeduct['price']);
    $newRequest->setPackageWeight($newRequest->getPackageWeight() - $totalsToDeduct['weight']);
    $newRequest->setPackageQty($newRequest->getPackageQty() - $totalsToDeduct['qty']);
    $newRequest->setFreeMethodWeight($newRequest->getFreeMethodWeight() - $totalsToDeduct['not_free_weight']);
    $newRequest->setPackageValueWithDiscount($newRequest->getPackageValue());
    $newRequest->setPackagePhysicalValue($newRequest->getPackageValue());

    return $newRequest;
}

public function canApplyFor($rates)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if (!count($request->getAllItems()))
        return false;

    $firstItem = current($request->getAllItems());
    if ($firstItem->getQuote()->isVirtual()){
        return false;
    }

    $rules = $this->getAllRules();
    foreach ($rules as $rule){
        foreach ($rates as $rate){
            if ($rule->match($rate)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public function getValidRules()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $hash = $this->getAddressHash($request);
    if ($this->getData('rules_by_'. $hash)){
        return $this->getData('rules_by_'. $hash);
    }

    $validRules = array();
    foreach ($this->getAllRules() as $rule){            
        $rule->afterLoad();
        if ($this->isCouponValid($request, $rule) && $rule->validate($request)){
            $validRules[] = $rule;
        }
    }

    $this->setData('rule_by_'. $hash, $validRules);

    return $validRules;
}

public function isCouponValid($request, $rule)
{
    $actualCouponCode  = trim(strtolower($rule->getCoupon()));
    $actualDiscountId  = intVal($rule->getDiscountId());

    if (!$actualCouponCode && !$actualDiscountId)
        return true;

    $providedCouponCodes = $this->getCouponCodes($request);

    if ($actualCouponCode){
        return (in_array($actualCouponCode, $providedCouponCodes));
    }

    if ($actualDiscountId){
        foreach ($providedCouponCodes as $code){
            $couponModel         = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon')->load($code, 'code');
            $providedDiscountId  = $couponModel->getRuleId();

            if ($providedDiscountId == $actualDiscountId){
                return true;
            }
            $couponModel = null;
        }

    }

    return false;
}

public function getCouponCodes($request)
{
    if (!count($request->getAllItems()))
        return array();

    $firstItem = current($request->getAllItems());
    $codes = trim(strtolower($firstItem->getQuote()->getCouponCode()));

    if (!$codes)
        return array();

    $providedCouponCodes = explode(",",$codes);

    foreach ($providedCouponCodes as $key => $code){
        $providedCouponCodes[$key] = trim($code);
    }

    return $providedCouponCodes;

}


public function getAllRules()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if (!$this->getData('rules_all')){
        $collection = $this->objectManager->create('Magesales\Shippingrules\Model\Rule')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addStoreFilter($request->getStoreId())
            ->addCustomerGroupFilter($this->getCustomerGroupId())
            ->addDaysFilter()
            ->setOrder('pos','asc')
            ->load();
        $this->setData('rules_all', $collection);
    }

    return $this->getData('rules_all');
}

public function getCustomerGroupId()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $groupId = 0;

    $firstItem = current($request->getAllItems());
    if ($firstItem->getQuote()->getCustomerId()){
        $groupId = $firstItem->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    }

    return $groupId;
}

public function getAddressHash($request)
{
    $addressCondition = $this->objectManager->create('Magesales\Shippingrules\Model\Rule\Condition\Address');
    $addressAttributes = $addressCondition->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();

    $hash = '';
    foreach ($addressAttributes as $code => $label) {
        $hash .= $request->getData($code) . $label;
    }

    return md5($hash);
}

public function aggregateTotals($group, $isFree)
{
    $totals = $this->initTotals();

    foreach ($group as $item) {

        if ($item->getParentItem() || $item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
            foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $qty        = $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                $notFreeQty = $item->getQty() * ($qty - $this->getFreeQty($child));

                $totals['qty']          += $qty;
                $totals['not_free_qty'] += $notFreeQty;

                $totals['price']          += $child->getBaseRowTotal();
                $totals['not_free_price'] += $child->getBasePrice() * $notFreeQty;

                if (!$item->getProduct()->getWeightType()) {
                    $totals['weight']          += $child->getWeight() * $qty;
                    $totals['not_free_weight'] += $child->getWeight() * $notFreeQty;
                }
            }
            if ($item->getProduct()->getWeightType()) {
                $totals['weight']          += $item->getWeight() * $item->getQty();
                $totals['not_free_weight'] += $item->getWeight() * ($item->getQty() - $this->getFreeQty($item));
            }
        }
        else { 

            $qty        = $item->getQty();
            $notFreeQty = ($qty - $this->getFreeQty($item));

            $totals['qty']          += $qty;
            $totals['not_free_qty'] += $notFreeQty;

            $totals['price']          += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
            $totals['not_free_price'] += $item->getBasePrice() * $notFreeQty;

            $totals['weight']          += $item->getWeight() * $qty;
            $totals['not_free_weight'] += $item->getWeight() * $notFreeQty;

        } }

    if ($isFree){
        $totals['not_free_price'] = $totals['not_free_weight'] = $totals['not_free_qty'] = 0;
    }

    return $totals;
}

public function getFreeQty($item)
{
    $freeQty = 0;
    if ($item->getFreeShipping()){
        $freeQty = (is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : $item->getQty());
    }
    return $freeQty;
}

public function initTotals()
{
    $totals = array(
        'price'              => 0,
        'not_free_price'     => 0,
        'weight'             => 0,
        'not_free_weight'    => 0,
        'qty'                => 0,
        'not_free_qty'       => 0,
    );
    return $totals;
}

public function getKey($rate)
{
    return $rate->getCarrier() . '~' . $rate->getMethod();
}

public function findRate($newRates, $rate)
{
    foreach ($newRates as $r){
        if ($this->getKey($r) == $this->getKey($rate)){
            return $r;
        }
    }

    return $rate;
}

public function getFee($rate)
{
    $k = $this->getKey($rate);
    if (empty($this->adjustments[$k]))
        return 0;

    return $this->adjustments[$k]['fee'];
}
}
```

**And log**

```
Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-59c528ed639da; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magesales/Shippingrules/Model/Validator.php on line 295 in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195

Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))

#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))

#2 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()

#5 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

I have to mention that I have a Shipping Method and the module in questions, surcharge, discount or replace the rates for this shipping method.

Comment: Please update your question with the file `app/code/Magesales/Shippingrules/Model/Validator.php` so that we can see the code.

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't know it is showing bold for list itens

Comment: I imagine that in the first attempt, string is null. SO if there is a way to run the function only if string is not null, maybe there is a solution. I wouldn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured it out, the issue lies in this function

```
public function getAddressHash($request)
{
    $addressCondition = $this->objectManager->create('Magesales\Shippingrules\Model\Rule\Condition\Address');
    $addressAttributes = $addressCondition->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();

    $hash = '';
    foreach ($addressAttributes as $code => $label) {
        $hash .= $request->getData($code) . $label;
    }

    return md5($hash);
}
```

This line: `$addressAttributes = $addressCondition->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();` expects to be an array, so that the `foreach` can work smoothly. But somehow it fails to return an array.

We cannot state the exact reason of why that line fails to return an array since we cannot see the code. But you can avoid this error the following way.

```
public function getAddressHash($request)
{
    $addressCondition = $this->objectManager->create('Magesales\Shippingrules\Model\Rule\Condition\Address');
    $addressAttributes = $addressCondition->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();

    $hash = '';
    if (is_array($addressAttributes)) {
        foreach ($addressAttributes as $code => $label) {
            $hash .= $request->getData($code) . $label;
        }
    }
    return md5($hash);
}
```

Here we explicitly make sure that `$addressAttributes` is of type `array` and only in that case `foreach` will get executed.

Hope that will resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello Rajeev. Thanks for your solution, but it didn't solve the issue. The notice only happens in the very first try. I tried other solutions. But it didn't work. I really don't know what to do. Anyway, I really appreciate your help.